# when parsing below line on a django framework ,The server page is empty.Inspect element says this error?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

```
html +='<a href="' + urland  + '">' + str(Dag.dag_id) + '</a><br>'
```

> django.db.models.query_utils.deferredattribute object="" at="" 0x040adbf0=""

Comment: Welcome to SO, you might need to take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Please provide more information and a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: do post how you are passing that to template, what is the expected outcome, with these lines its impossible for anyone to help you

Comment: thank you for answering. actually i can't be specified on what the problems...there are lot of it......

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that you are using a database attribute whose value is not yet loaded?

[Determine if an attribute is a `DeferredAttribute` in django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28222469/determine-if-an-attribute-is-a-deferredattribute-in-django)

Answer (score 0):

Give a respose of your view,that how you render data to this template.
Your question is not clear..

Try this..

html +=' {{ Dag.dag_id }}
'